# No Robots.txt but I want to noindex a page

Tags: php

I have an HTML/PHP/CSS site, very simple, and I have no robots.txt file for it. The site is indexed, it's all great.

But now I created a page for something I need, and I want to make that one page noindex.

Do I have to create a robots.txt file for it, or is there an easier way to do it without having to create a robots.txt?

Also, I did Google for this before asking, and I came across an article that instructed to put the following code on your page under the `<head>` code:

```
<META NAME="ROBOTS" CONTENT="NOINDEX, NOFOLLOW">
```

I did that. However, after I checked the page here: http://www.seoreviewtools.com/bulk-meta-robots-checker/

It says: Meta robots: Not found
Explanation: There are no restrictions for indexing or serving detected.

So then, how can I make that page noindex?

Comment: bots dont have to obey robots.txt or the robots meta tag - what bot are you trying to stop?

Comment: Most web crawlers will obey the meta tag above. The tool even lists `<meta name=”robots” content=”noindex, nofollow”>` as working - its possible sensitive to case?

Comment: the meta tag is fine, but you'd still be wasting bandwith because every bot will STILL download it - they HAVE to do, otherwise they'll never see the meta tag. Just create a robots.txt. The spiders will be trying to fetch it ANYWAYS, so you might as well make use of it.

Comment: I created a robots.txt, and following some stuff I read online, I put this in there `User-agent: *
Disallow: 
Disallow: /cgi-bin/
Disallow: /brandon/` Is that okay? I'm looking to not index the folder named "brandon"

Answer (score 0):

Although having a robots.txt file is the best you can do, there is never a guarantee that a search robot will not index that page. I believe most, if not all respectable search engines will follow the restrictions in that file but there are plenty of other bots out there that don't.

That said, if you don't link to the page anywhere, no search engine will index it - at least in theory: if you or other people access that page and their browser or an extension submits that page for indexing, it ends up being indexed anyway.